# Running Isolation Forest algorithm in R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to run [Isolation Forest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iforest/) algorithm in R version 3.2.0 within R studio. R gives me the following error:

> Error: package ‘IsolationForest’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

The issue is that the algorithm can run before R version 2.10 which is not supported by R studio (which I tend to use for other reasons). Another version of the algorithm is implemented in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest) in Python, but I didn't managed to invoke it into R.

Do you have any solution for this?
Either enabling the native package to work in R within R studio or using scikit-learn in R works fine for me.

Comment: Would using a  2.x kernel possible?

Comment: @Mathias711 Maybe it would, but honestly I don't know anything about it. Could you provide some more info?

Comment: You can easily point RStudio to use a different R kernel, meaning that RStudio would use a different R version or 32/64 bit. More information [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R). In short, find and install R 2.x version, in RStudio Tools-> Global options -> General -> R Version and select the R 2,x version you just installed. In this way, the IsolationForest should be able to be installed and imported. You could face problems with other packages unfortunately

Comment: try installing the [r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=479) version. `install.packages("IsolationForest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. That works on my machine.

Comment: @Mathias711 Actually, I tried that. :) When I install R version on which Isolation forest should run (the package is built on version prior to version 2.10) the R studio won't work (R studio supports R from 2.11.1).

Comment: @phiver It won't work on my side. Throws an error `Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran:
  ‘IsolationForest’.  These will not be installed`.

Comment: @Makaroni, do you have Rtools installed? You need to be able to compile source packages.

Comment: @phiver It seems that Rstudio loaded the package successfully after installing R tools. Huge thanks for the answer!